# JsonSchema for struct to use string representation of struct rather than the struct fields

Tags: json, rust

Here is my struct

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Clone, Copy, Debug, JsonSchema)]
pub struct Position {
    x: SignedDecimal,
    y: SignedDecimal,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Clone, Copy, Debug, JsonSchema)]
pub struct SignedDecimal {
    value: Decimal256,
    sign:  bool,
}
```

An example output of the default schema looks like this:

```
{
    "x": { "value": "1.5", "sign": true },
    "y": { "value": "1.5", "sign": true }
}
```

What I want it to look like is this:

```
{
    "x": "1.5",
    "y": "1.5"
}
```

But I can't seem to get the Schemars macros to do what I want.
I've tried many things, like this for example:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Clone, Copy, Debug, JsonSchema)]
#[schemars(schema_with = "String")]
pub struct SignedDecimal {
    value: Decimal256,
    sign:  bool,
}
```

Ideally I am not using any additional macros on the Position struct, and instead just modifying the SignedDecimal struct. All of the relevant String impls have been defined, I just can't make the macro do what I want.

Comment: What is `Decimal256`? And shouldn't `x` and `y` be `SignedDecimal`s instead of `Decimal256`s?

Comment: Not an answer, but from what you want, wouldn't serde be more suitable than JsonSchema?

Comment: The [schemars documentation](https://docs.rs/schemars/latest/schemars/index.html#serde-compatibility) says it snoops on the serde attributes and tries to match, so [I tried](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3d891d3b305a788648a77d644d447a0a) with the `#[serde(from)]` and `#[serde(into)]` attributes but they didn't change the schema. :/ You might have to implement `JsonSchema` manually.

Comment: @kmdreko I made a mistake on the text of the post here. Yes x and y are both SignedDecimal. I'll update that. Decimal256 is an unsigned decimal type, which I am trying to make a signed version of.

Comment: @kmdreko yes I've tried that as well and it didn't work for me either.

Comment: @wisha I need JsonSchema so that I can interface with a specific external api.

Comment: Just to be clear, is your problem with the JSON you get when you serialize a value, or with the schema generated by [`schema_for`](https://docs.rs/schemars/0.8.10/schemars/macro.schema_for.html)?

Comment: @Jmb Serialize works fine. It is the actual schema that is the problem.

Comment: @user3912409 then maybe using [`schema_for_value`](https://docs.rs/schemars/0.8.10/schemars/macro.schema_for_value.html) instead of deriving `JsonSchema` would get you what you want?

Comment: You could [overwrite](https://graham.cool/schemars/examples/7-custom_serialization/) part of the generated schema with `#[schemars(with = "String")]` or `#[schemars(schema_with = "…")]` - but what do you actually want the generated schema to look like? What you're showing is a JSON object, not its schema.

Answer (score 1):

Not a perfect solution but I'm going to manually implement JsonSchema since I can't figure out how to make it work with the provided macros.

```
impl JsonSchema for SignedDecimal {
    fn schema_name() -> String {
        "signed_decimal".to_string()
    }

    fn json_schema(gen: &mut schemars::gen::SchemaGenerator) -> schemars::schema::Schema {
        String::json_schema(gen)
    }

    fn is_referenceable() -> bool {
        true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could overwrite the schema for fields with `#[schemars(schema_with = "…")]`. For example:

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Clone, Copy, Debug, JsonSchema)]
pub struct Position {
    #[schemars(schema_with = "pretend_to_be_number_string")]
    x: SignedDecimal,
    #[schemars(schema_with = "pretend_to_be_number_string")]
    y: SignedDecimal,
}

fn pretend_to_be_number_string(
    gen: &mut schemars::gen::SchemaGenerator,
) -> schemars::schema::Schema {
    use schemars::schema::*;
    let mut obj = SchemaObject::default();
    obj.instance_type = Some(SingleOrVec::Single(InstanceType::String.into()));
    obj.string().pattern = Some("[+-]?[0-9]*\\.[0-9]*".into()); // TODO: rudimentary
    let obj = Schema::Object(obj);
    gen.definitions_mut()
        .insert("SignedDecimal".into(), obj.clone());
    let mut or = SchemaObject::default();
    or.reference = Some("#/definitions/SignedDecimal".into());
    Schema::Object(or)
}
```

will result in the schema

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "title": "Position",
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "x",
    "y"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "x": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/SignedDecimal"
    },
    "y": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/SignedDecimal"
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "SignedDecimal": {
      "type": "string",
      "pattern": "[+-]?[0-9]*\\.[0-9]*"
    }
  }
}
```

There is probably a way of not having to specify this on every field, but I can't find it.

Comment: This works, but the problem is that SigneDecimal is a pub struct and other people will be using it and the schema needs to be correct for everyone. My solution is manually impling JsonSchema like this
`
impl JsonSchema for SignedDecimal {
    fn schema_name() -> String {
        "signed_decimal".to_string()
    }

    fn json_schema(gen: &mut schemars::gen::SchemaGenerator) -> schemars::schema::Schema {
        String::json_schema(gen)
    }

    fn is_referenceable() -> bool {
        true
    }
}
`